# Different TensorFlow version for local running the google Colaboratory pages

Tags: tensorflow, google-colaboratory

I am using [this Google Colaboratory page locally](https://colab.research.google.com/github/magenta/ddsp/blob/master/ddsp/colab/demos/timbre_transfer.ipynb#scrollTo=6wZde6CBya9k), So I have one TensorFlow = 2.2.0  on my Conda app, but when I want to run another Google Colaboratory page like below, it needs to run TensorFlow>= 2.5 :

[image]

So, I asked here to find out how could have two TensorFlow for running Google Colaboratory page locally on my Ubuntu OS.

**Update:**

I have changed the Conda environment and updated the TensorFlow, but I get this error.

```
(tensorflow2_5) so@so-Lenovo-ideapad-310-15IKB:/$  pip install tensorflow --upgrade

...
tensorflow
  Attempting uninstall: numpy
    Found existing installation: numpy 1.20.2
    Uninstalling numpy-1.20.2:
      Successfully uninstalled numpy-1.20.2
  Attempting uninstall: grpcio
    Found existing installation: grpcio 1.37.1
    Uninstalling grpcio-1.37.1:
      Successfully uninstalled grpcio-1.37.1
  Attempting uninstall: typing-extensions
    Found existing installation: typing-extensions 3.10.0.0
    Uninstalling typing-extensions-3.10.0.0:
      Successfully uninstalled typing-extensions-3.10.0.0
  Attempting uninstall: tensorflow-estimator
    Found existing installation: tensorflow-estimator 2.4.0
    Uninstalling tensorflow-estimator-2.4.0:
      Successfully uninstalled tensorflow-estimator-2.4.0
  Attempting uninstall: tensorboard
    Found existing installation: tensorboard 2.4.1
    Uninstalling tensorboard-2.4.1:
      Successfully uninstalled tensorboard-2.4.1
  Attempting uninstall: h5py
    Found existing installation: h5py 2.10.0
    Uninstalling h5py-2.10.0:
      Successfully uninstalled h5py-2.10.0
  Attempting uninstall: gast
    Found existing installation: gast 0.3.3
    Uninstalling gast-0.3.3:
      Successfully uninstalled gast-0.3.3
  Attempting uninstall: flatbuffers
    Found existing installation: flatbuffers 20210226132247
    Uninstalling flatbuffers-20210226132247:
      Successfully uninstalled flatbuffers-20210226132247
  Attempting uninstall: tensorflow
    Found existing installation: tensorflow 2.4.1
    Uninstalling tensorflow-2.4.1:
      Successfully uninstalled tensorflow-2.4.1
ERROR: pip's dependency resolver does not currently take into account all the packages that are installed. This behaviour is the source of the following dependency conflicts.
crepe 0.0.11 requires h5py<3.0.0,>=2.7.0, but you have h5py 3.1.0 which is incompatible.
Successfully installed flatbuffers-1.12 gast-0.4.0 grpcio-1.34.1 h5py-3.1.0 keras-nightly-2.5.0.dev2021032900 numpy-1.19.5 tensorboard-2.5.0 tensorboard-data-server-0.6.1 tensorflow-2.5.0 tensorflow-estimator-2.5.0 typing-extensions-3.7.4.3
```

Comment: Is there anything wrong with upgrading tensorflow on your local machine? The above image, shows the notebook is using `tensorflow_probability`, or `tfp` for short, which needs tensorflow >=2.5. But the previous one probably does not use `tfp` and also runs on tensorflow 2.2. Upgrading to TF 2.5 will solve the problem. However I did not understand what is the problem exactly.

Comment: Did you tried as suggested above?

Comment: Thanks, **kaveh** and **TFer2**, I don't test it, but I will try it during this week and if not forgot, I will update this question.

Comment: I have some problem in installing new TensorFlow by `crepe` and `h5py` module, so I updated the question.